# Cannot open any CSHTML file in a certain project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2013

When I open a CSHTML file in one specific ASP.NET MVC project, visual studio 2013 crashes.

I can open other files in this project and I can open CSHTML files in other projects.

I and a coworker work with this project on other computers without trouble.

I've deleted the entire project from my computer and cloned a fresh copy from our Git repo with the same results.

Any clues?

**EDIT:**

I reviewed the windows logs and found the following error:

> Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.ArgumentException Stack: at
>   System.String.CompareTo(System.Object) at
>   System.Web.Razor.Parser.RazorParser.ParseCore(System.Web.Razor.Text.ITextDocument)
>   at
>   System.Web.Razor.Parser.RazorParser.Parse(System.Web.Razor.Text.ITextDocument)
>   at
>   System.Web.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCodeCore(System.Web.Razor.Text.ITextDocument,
>   System.String, System.String, System.String,
>   System.Nullable`1) at
>   System.Web.Razor.Editor.BackgroundParser+BackgroundThread.ParseChange(System.Web.Razor.Text.ITextBuffer,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken) at
>   System.Web.Razor.Editor.BackgroundParser+BackgroundThread.WorkerLoop()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: It may be possible to attach another instance of Visual Studio to the crashing one (before it crashes) and identify which Razor file(s) is causing trouble.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to attach the process, but it didn't provide any additional information. The error occurs on any cshtml file I try to open in this project.

Comment: What is you try creating a new blank cshtml and opening that? It's definitely a tricky one to debug

Comment: I attempted to create a new view without a model and no specified layout. VS went through scaffolding, opened the new view, then crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved this by changing

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
```

to

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

in the web config.